# Stop a form from redirecting after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm utilizing a form built from wufoo in my web app. I'm trying to stop the form from pushing the submit URL and just give a promt to the user. I've tried inputting `e.preventdefault` and `return.false` in my .js file but the information is still submitting. There's nothing in my .js file except for validation rules.

Please see my jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ws2q8wgw/

What am I doing wrong? I thought just inputting $('#form166').submit(false); would do the trick.

Comment: `$('#form166').on('submit', function() { return false; });` perhaps? How are you implementing it?

Comment: Maybe your current form has any other listener. Try to identify the listener that your form has, and then you can override them.

Comment: What's `return.false`? And where's your actual [mcve]? We need your JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: return.false or e.preventdefault is standard functions to stop the action.. i've tried adding both to my .js but still nothing. i'll edit my post with my actual code but honestly there is nothing substantial. what i posted currently is the most important content.

Comment: what does "adding ... to my .js" mean? What is that ".js" you keep referring to?

Comment: There's no period in `return false`

Comment: @Igor adding the code to my .js file. The form consists of two files. One is the standard HTML which is where the form is and the .js is for my validation rules.. so the user can't just enter random stuff.

Comment: @j08691 i've edited my post if you can see my jsfiddle thanks!

Comment: @chronotrigga - I don't see any validation connected to form submission in your fiddle

Comment: @Igor Yes unfortunately I removed it since it wasn't working. trying a new method now, just updated the jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Use the unload event ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload)).  You can cancel the submit.

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to give a promt to the user?

This should do the job.

```
onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
```

Or all together

```
<form id="form166" name="form166" class="wufoo topLabel page" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate action="https://boiron.wufoo.com/forms/z16px8aw1sdfff/#public" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/823yLec4/